# How do I upload and use .pyc files on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, bytecode, python-2.7, pyc

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Sandbox), the Python 2.7 GAE runtime no longer restricts access to bytecode:

> The Python 2.7 runtime no longer restricts access to Python bytecode. Libraries that generate or manipulate bytecode (e.g. the `jinja2` templating library) can do so in this runtime.
>
> You can upload and use `.pyc`, but not in combination with `.py` files. You can upload zip files containing `.py` or `.pyc` files (or a combination).

How do I take avantage of this?

Part of my `app.yaml` `skip-files` directive has this line:

```
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[o]
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py
```

Then I uploaded my app to Google App Engine. When I tested it, I get an ImportError (in the logs):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 225, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
ImportError: No module named main
```

I'm using the `threadsafe: true` option, so my main handler looks like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

How come Google App Engine cannot detect my `main.pyc` file? Are there any necessary special file tree configurations?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What's the point?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, just want to try it out. I understand that speed is gained only at instance startup.

Comment: Have you tried `.*\.py$` or `.*\.py[^c]`?  I don't know if there's an implicit `$` added to the regexes in skip_files, but '\.py` matches `".pyc"`.